# VS2012 - appears to be trying to link to DLL vs. LIB

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, static-libraries

I'm getting linker errors along the lines of `LINK2001: unresolved external symbol "... __declspec (dllimport) public: __thiscall <function> ..." <internally coded equivalent>`.

The functions are provided in a static library as a dependency of the main project.

I have confirmed the library was created successfully and it is referenced under `Framework and References` with a correct `Full Path` including .lib extension.

Does `__declspec (dllimport)` mean it is expecting a DLL? If so, there isn't one.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the header file correctly? Have you defined the symbols that give you static linking rather than dynamic linking?

Comment: It was a missing preprocessor compile define to use a static library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, __declspec(dllimport) tells it to expect a DLL, and is used with an import library (also a .lib).

Check the header files that you're using to provide prototypes of the functions in the static library to the main project that depends on it.  It may be a static library, but it sounds like somewhere in those common header files is "__declspec(dllimport)" or a macro that expands to it in those function and/or class declarations.